# how to use variable in range using vba

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have written code for generating graph using vba. everything working correctly ,but problem is i want to use variable for selecting particular column 
the code is :

```
Set x = Range("$CF$2", Range("$CF$2").End(xlDown))
Set y = Range("$CG$2", Range("$CG$2").End(xlDown))
Dim c As Chart
Set c = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set c = c.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=assume)
With c
.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

' set other chart properties

With .Parent
.Top = Range("cl1").Top
.Left = Range("cl12").Left
.Name = "c"
End With
End With

Dim s As Series
Set s = c.SeriesCollection(1)
With s
.Values = y
 .XValues = x
' set other series properties

End With
```

I want to use variable `COLs` in first to line they are

```
Set x = Range("$CF$2", Range("$CF$2").End(xlDown))
Set y = Range("$CG$2", Range("$CG$2").End(xlDown))
```

`COLs` is variable of string

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question, could you please explain again? What is `COLs` and how are you supposed to use it? Could you give an example of `COLs`?

Comment: thank you for your time.             COLs is variable which holds the  value given by user example "A","B".... column names...... so i want to set COLs value to x

Comment: So `x` and `y` are the rows, and `COLs` is the column? Or can `COLs` be more than one column?

Comment: NOOOO... x and y are range here .. i am using x and y for assigning the value to axis in the graph so example                                             Set x = Range("$CF$2", Range("$CF$2").End(xlDown))
Set y = Range("$CG$2", Range("$CG$2").End(xlDown))                               in range instead of giving "$CF$2", Range("$CF$2").End(xlDown)"      i want to use variable like set x = range(COLs)

Comment: OK. I think. Please see answer below... :)

Comment: I want to explain it in clear ..... user will select the column and that column name will b stored in variable COLs.................. when I dra the graph using vba .. I want x-axis value to be value of COLS variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but if you want a `Range` object based on a string, why not try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestRange()

    '***** Declare variables
    Dim oX As Range
    Dim sCOLs As String

    '***** Select column
    sCOLs = "A"


    '***** Set Range based on column from sCOLs
    Set oX = Range(sCOLs & "2", Range(sCOLs & "2").End(xlDown))

    '***** Do something with oX
    Debug.Print TypeName(oX)

    '***** Clean up
    Set oX = Nothing

End Sub
```

You could also try and have the whole range as a string, maybe a bit cleaner code?

```
Dim sRange as String

sRange = "A2"

Set oX = Range(sRange, Range(sRange).End(xlDown))
```

Comment: I want to explain it in clear ..... user will select the column and that column name will b stored in variable COLs.................. when I dra the graph using vba .. I want x-axis value to be value of COLS variable...

Comment: If the user only selects the column, how do you know how many rows to include? If it is always rows 2->End, the above examples will work - here I assumed the user selected column A.

Comment: thank you it is working as required .. i modified ma code like this  Set x = Range("$CH$2", Range("$CH$2").End(xlDown))
   Set y = Range(COLs & "2", Range(COLs & "2").End(xlDown))                here i used COLs variable for y... same way how can i use COLs.offset(-1)...  I mean i want use previous column of COLs... for x value

Comment: You already have the range you need in `y`, so you could just assign `x` with an offset: `Set x = y.Offset(0, -1)`.

Comment: OK, great! Please close the question by clicking the gray checkmark on the answer.

Comment: Hello I have written code for adding the value into cells ..LIKE A1,A2,A3, and so on code is
Sum = Abs(rangex1) + Abs(rangex2)

Debug.Print (Sum)

step_size = Sum / XDim

step_half = step_size / 2

start_point = rangex1 + step_half
Debug.Print (step_size)
Debug.Print (step_half)
Debug.Print (start_point)

For i = 1 To XDim

Range("A" & i) = start_point
start_point = start_point + step_size

Next i

now i want to add value into cells by column wise for example:A1,B1,C1,D1,E1 and so on...
may i no how can i use the for loop(syntax)                                     @olle

Comment: I think you need to post a new question, I don't see the connection to this Q+A. OK?

Comment: But i tried to post new question it is showing error called Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

It does not meet our quality standards.

Comment: I have posted my new question please reply to that

Comment: sCOLs is a horrible variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Inputbox to have the user click on a certain cell. This then creates a variable "UserRange" which contains the cell reference you can use.

```
Sub test()

Dim UserRange As Range

Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
UserRange.Value = "Test"

End Sub
```